# how to to auto login after signup with next-auth and firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

im new to nextauth and firebase, i am trying to create a basic user system, currently when signing up you get redirected to the login page but i would like to automaticly login the user after signup, i am using firebase auth and when signing up i get returned a user, is there a way to login using this user object?

i can auto signin using the password and email gatherd from the singup page but i would like to use the user object from firebase to login, as it would be cleaner.

```
 signIn('credentials', {
      email: formdata.get("email"), 
      password: formdata.get("password"),
      redirect: true, 
      callbackUrl: '/'})
  }`login method`

const signup = (formdata : FormData) => {
    setEmail((formdata.get("email") as string))
    setPassword((formdata.get("password") as string))
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(user => {
      
    });
  };`singup, createUser returns a user object from firebase`
```

Answer (score 1):

Users are automatically signed in after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` completes successfully. The `user` object you receive in the callback describes that user account. You don't have to do anything else, but you might want to follow to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to set up a listener to trigger after that happens, then do whatever you want in the listener callback.